# matplotlib does not plot and gives a NameError in shape_base.py

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Help would be greatly appreciated! I got an error and cannot find a solution online. I recently installed a new desktop and previously working code now gives me errors.

I am trying to load and plot an image using matplotlib.pyplot in spyder, anaconda, windows. When calling imshow, I get an error. I get the same error when calling the plot function.

I verfied that matplotlib is installed by running conda install matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
```

gives the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-19-61e052f4bd52>", line 1, in <module>
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",     line 2787, in plot
return gca().plot(

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 920, in gca
return gcf().gca(**kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1932, in gca
return self.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1414, in add_subplot
a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 66, in __init__
self.update_params()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 127, in update_params
return_all=True)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py", line 489, in get_position
gridspec.get_grid_positions(figure)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py", line 127, in get_grid_positions
cell_hs = np.cumsum(np.column_stack([sep_heights, cell_heights]).flat)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 633, in column_stack
_arrays_for_stack_dispatcher(tup, stacklevel=2)

NameError: name '_warn_for_nonsequence' is not defined

<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

Comment: It could be that you system missing numpy

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav for this suggestion. I thought of this as well. I tried conda install numpy and tells me "All requested packages already installed" I will however try numpy to test

Comment: `File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 633, in column_stack
_arrays_for_stack_dispatcher(tup, stacklevel=2)` means to me that numpy is present

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and then re-installing matplotlib?

Comment: You should try to uninstall both numpy and matplotlib, and then reinstall matplotlib - this will make sure the matplotlib version will automatically install the correct version of numpy (it seems it is looking for something which is missing in the numpy version you have installed)

Comment: will try this reinstallation

Comment: Reinstalling helped! Yes! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by reinstalling matplotlib and numpy and spyder

tl;dr - short instruction:

- Reinstalling matplotlib solved the problem! 
  reinstall from anaconda commandline dosbox (admin rights)

  - `conda uninstall matplotlib`
  - `conda uninstall numpy`
- maybe also reinstall spyder from anaconda command line dosbox (also admin 
  rights)

  - `conda install spyder`

full story (please follow the short instruction above):

For the interested reader; it took some trial&error, here is what happened:

I first typed `conda uninstall matplotlib` from the spyder commandline/kernel. Did not work; restarted spyder with administrator rights. Some stuff got uninstalled, rest did't. In fact, this made things worse I got more errors which even showed up on the spyder kernel when restarting. Tried `conda uninstall numpy` .. then it typed: `conda install matplotlib` (in admin mode). Errors kept popping up. My suspicion is it was related to interaction with spyder/gui from spyder.

So I closed down spider and (admin rights) opened up an anaconda console cmd box in dosmode. 
Then I typed `conda uninstall matplotlib` .. everything went ok. 
Then `conda uninstall numpy` .. ok ... 
Then `conda install matplotlib` ... ok

Then I tried too launch spyder again from the taskbar ... nothing happened! Spyder appears to have gone. (so I guess indeed there was some entanglement/interaction with the uninstall of matplotlib & numpy) AAHH!

So I opened up anaconda navigator ... install spyder ... error!!!

Then to the anaconda command line again typed `conda install spyder` ...
this finally worked and now its all working again.

Still dont know what caused the error but apparently the somewhat cumbersome reinstallation solved the problem.

Hope this helps someone in the future